# IS there a possibility to get the "same" attribute into one column from different tables?

Tags: sql, teradata

So I have two the two tables with a primary key **month_cd**:

Table A:

| month_cd | stuff | stuff2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | null |
| Second | 2 | null |
| Third | null | 2 |

Table B:

| month_cd | stuff | stuff2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | null | 2 |
| Third | 3 | null |
| Fourth | 4 | 3 |

I need them to look like this in the third table C.

Table C:

| month_cd | stuff | stuff2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | 2 |
| Second | 2 | null |
| Third | 3 | 2 |
| Fourth | 4 | 3 |

I tried doing **full outer join** with **coalesce(A.month_cd, B.month_cd, C.month_cd)**, but somewhy it gives me doubles like

Table C:

| month_cd | stuff | stuff2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | null |
| First | null | 2 |
| Second | 2 | null |
| Third | 3 | null |
| Third | null | 2 |
| Fourth | 4 | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, a full outer join should work here:

```sql
SELECT
    COALESCE(a.month_cd, b.month_cd) AS month_cd,
    COALESCE(a.stuff, b.stuff) AS stuff,
    COALESCE(a.stuff2, b.stuff2) AS stuff2
FROM TableA a
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB b
    ON b.month_cd = a.month_cd;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works just fine! I forgot to coalesce the other attributes too. Just wondering, what if we had different columns (stuff3 instead of stuff2 in table B), would that work just the same?